# How to fix the error to load pdf document on mpdf 5.7 version in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

How to fix the error to load pdf document on mpdf 5.7 version in codeigniter?
PHP VERSION: 7.2
MPDF VERSION: 5.7
CI VERSION: 3.1.3

Answer (score 0):

mpdf 5.7

Use this accordingly in your ontroller:

```
public function save_pdf($id)
{ 
    //load mPDF library
    $this->load->library('m_pdf'); 
    
    $data['qr_details'] =  $this->equip_model->get_qr_details($id);

    $data['view'] = 'admin/inspected_equip/m_for_pdf';
    $html=$this->load->view('admin/pdf_layout', $data, true);

     //load the pdf.php by passing our data and get all data in $html variable.
    $pdfFilePath ="PDF-NAME-HERE-".time().".pdf";       
    //actually, you can pass mPDF parameter on this load() function
    //$pdf = $this->m_pdf->load();
    $pdf=new mPDF(); 
    //generate the PDF!
    $stylesheet = '<style>'.file_get_contents('Link-stylesheet-URL-here').'</style>';
    
    // apply external css
    $pdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);
    $pdf->WriteHTML($html,2);
    //offer it to user via browser download! (The PDF won't be saved on your server HDD)
    $pdf->Output($pdfFilePath, "D");
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I followed the steps, it works fine for generating pdf, and downloading pdf but not for viewing it in chrome. It shows error to load pdf document. What will be the issue? Can you please help me out?

Comment: Share Error Please